# Java code to get the list of file name from a folder

Tags: java, file

I have a scenario where around 5600 files are present.
I am able to retrieve the file names by using the below code:

```
 String path = "D:\\Projects worked upon\\ANZ\\Anz new\\Files\\329703588_20160328124733595\\Output"; String files;

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
         {
         files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
             if (files.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
             {
                System.out.println(files);

              }
```

, but i need only the first part  For Eg:if the file name in folder is "abc_Transformed.xml" , i require only abc .. How to get it ?

Comment: Look into split example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: 1) `s.split("_")[0]`. 2) `s.substring(0, s.indexOf('_'))`. 3) regex: `(.*?)_`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring method to find first string.

```
 if (files.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
             {
                String result = files.substring(0, files.indexOf("_"));
                System.out.println(result);               
              }
```

your whole code

```
 String path = "D:\\Projects worked upon\\ANZ\\Anz new\\Files\\329703588_20160328124733595\\Output"; String files;     
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();      
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        { 
         if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
          { 
             files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
             if (files.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
             { 
               String result = files.substring(0, files.indexOf("_"));
               System.out.println(result);      
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

The information about the files is basically irrelevant. You are after some basic `String` manipulation functions.

You could try something using [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) like:

```
String[] pieces = files.split("_");
String first = pieces[0];   // should be equal to "abc"
```

Or something using [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [String.substr()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) like:

```
int indexOfUnderscore = files.indexOf("_");
String first = files.substr(0, indexOfUnderscore); // should be equal to "abc"
```

If you're new to Java, it's worth spending the time to review all the [String functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).